# How to cut a keyword in a String (Java)?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string in Java:

```
String test = "Goof 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24";
```

Now i want to cut the word "Goof" away from the String and i want to save the originally 23N input in a separate string (but how can a delete this keyword and save the originally input "23N" or "33*")

```
for(String tmpTest : test.split(",")){

  if (tmpTest.toLowerCase.contains("goof")){
      String separateString = // implementation unclear
  }

}
```

Comment: Look at the [API docs of class `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), it contains a lot of useful methods that you can use for this.

Comment: `String test = Goof 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24;` is this a Java snipplet?

Comment: `Goof 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24;` this isn't correct String, do you mean `String test =" Goof 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24";` instead?

Comment: you are right, i have correct it !

Comment: It would help direct the answers to show the actual formatted output you want.

Comment: just replace the relevant string part like this tmpTest.replace("goof", "");

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try this out:

```
    String test = "Goof 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24";
    String value = test.replaceFirst("Goof", "");
```

> Output: 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24

Or, if you need to remove all the versions of 'Goof' without case matching then check this :

```
    String test = "Goof 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24";
    // (?i) in the below regex will ignore case while matching
    String value = test.replaceAll("(?i)Goof\\s*", "");
```

> Output: 23N, 45, 88, 33*, 12-24

Comment: ok but Goof can by written like "GooF" or "GOOF" or "GoOf" or "gooF" and so on. Now the replaceAll method doesn´t work very well :-(

Comment: The second approach in my post should answer your query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help you. Replace your `if` statement with the one below.

```
int index = tmpTest.toLowerCase().indexOf("goof");
if (index >= 0) {
  String value = tmpTest.substring(index + 5);
}
```

Also, be careful with the compile errors you have in your code.

Comment: This will work only if the word 'goof' is at the start of the string.

Comment: It works when goof is in front of the other value. It seems like this is the rule.

Comment: But it could be the case, where the user needs to get entire string with 'goof' removed from it. Your code does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`

```
String test = "Goof 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24";
test = test.replaceAll("Goof","").replaceAll("GOOF","");
```

Comment: ok but Goof can by written like "GooF" or "GOOF" or "GoOf" or "gooF" and so on. Now the replaceAll method doesn´t work very well :-(

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use `replaceAll` with regex ***ignoring case***. You can use `Pattern.quote()` for this purpose:

```
String keyword = "gOOf";

String test = "Goof 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24";
String replaceString = "(?i)" + Pattern.quote(keyword);

test = test.replaceAll(replaceString, "");
System.out.println(test);
```

**Output:**

> 23N, 45, 88,  33*, 12-24

Here, it doesn't matter how 'gOOf' is written it would replaceAll occurrences using the regex.

Comment: But i need this output: 23N, 45, 88, 33*, 12-24

Comment: @Marwief yes, so I have changed the code here - look at the edited lines

Comment: Can you help me again? How can i implemented something like this with the regular expressions: "if (test.contains(replaceString))"

Comment: @Marwief You can do the check without the regex too: `if (test.toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase()))`

Answer (score 0):

Just one more way to do it...

```
        String text = "Goof     23N, 45, 88, GoOF 33*, 12-24";
        //if you want to remove trailing spaces use 'goof\\s*' as regex
        String regex="goof";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);  
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);        
        System.out.println(m.replaceAll(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String GOOF = "goof";
String input = "Goof 23N, 45, 88, GOOF 33*, 12-24";
String inputLawerCase = input.toLowerCase();
String inputWithoutGoof = inputLawerCase.replaceFirst(GOOF, "");
String output = input.substring(input.length() - inputWithoutGoof.length());

//In case Goof is not at the beginning of the string
int goofIndex = inputLawerCase.indexOf(GOOF);
output = input.substring(0, goofIndex) + input.substring(goofIndex + GOOF.length());
```

Answer (score -1):

Time for a little pseudocode me thinks.

**Step 1**

You want to split the `String` up into `tokens`. You can do this using [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

```
Let input equal "this, is, just, a, GOOFtest".
// It's a comma that separates each token, so let's split on that.
Let tokens equal input.split(",").
```

***NOTE:*** If you want to preserve your input as a `String`, then don't do this step.

**Step 2**

Parse your data, removing `"GOOF"` as you see it. You can use the [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for that.

```
for every token in tokens
    let token equal token.replaceAll("GOOF", nothing).
```

***NOTE***: If `GOOF` can come in different cases, it's time for some `regexp`. This is called a `metalanguage`, and it's designed to analyse and manipulate `String`s. What you want to do, is not take `case` into account, and you can achieve this using the `?i` operator.

```
String regex = "(?i)GOOF";
String parsedInput = input.replaceAll(regex, "");
// And that's the only bit of Java you're getting!!
```

**Step 3**

????

**Step 4**

Profit! You have an array containing only the values, without `GOOF` appearing.

Comment: What language := is belong to?

Comment: Pseudocode should not use symbols. Just pure English using logical explanations.

Comment: I think in this instance OP will survive.

Comment: ARE YOU NOT ENTERTAINED?